# ionic 4 tabs starter - what does href="/tabs/(contact:contact)" do

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing, ionic4

I'm exploring the new navigation in ionic 4 (type angular) and in the tabs projects you can find this

```
href="/tabs/(contact:contact)"
```

What does the

```
(contact:contact)
```

do? Is it some sort replacement for the former navParams?

Comment: Just an addition to fatemes answer: The old navigation using `NavController` will indeed be deprecated in Ionic 4. Instead Ionic will use the official Angular router. Also check out the [migration guide on this topic](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration#navigation).

Comment: With [4.0.0-beta.18](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-beta18-2018-12-13) the usage of ion-tab was removed and it's not necessary to use named outlets.

Comment: **Current Demo** (@ionic/angular 4.0.1) + **Explanation** can be found [here](https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tab-routing/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just a way to specify which outlet to use, and follows the format of `(outlet:path)`. If we specify `(contact:contact)` that means that we want to use the outlet with a name of contact and we also want the route path to be contact. You could define multiple paths for a single outlet, in that case, you might have a link like: `/tabs/(contact:detail)`

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: HomePage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'contact',
                outlet: 'contact', //outlet
                loadChildren: '../contact/contact.module#ContactModule'
            },

            ...
       ]
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and example!